# Compiling HSL_ME57 and interfacing with C code

Tags: fortran, compiling, matrix-factorization

Has anyone here had any success (or at least tried) compiling the HSL_ME57 (or similar such as MA57, etc.) matrix factorization libraries? Do any C wrappers exist for the Fortran function calls? I'm not having much luck compiling the library using GCC 4.9 (latest version). Here are the errors I am getting:

```
gfortran  -g -O2 -c -o sdeps90.o sdeps90.f90
/tmp/ccmoJQYa.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccmoJQYa.s:118: Error: unknown .loc sub-directive `discriminator'
/tmp/ccmoJQYa.s:118: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `2'
/tmp/ccmoJQYa.s:122: Error: unknown .loc sub-directive `discriminator'
/tmp/ccmoJQYa.s:122: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `2'
/tmp/ccmoJQYa.s:126: Error: unknown .loc sub-directive `discriminator'
/tmp/ccmoJQYa.s:126: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `2'
/tmp/ccmoJQYa.s:130: Error: unknown .loc sub-directive `discriminator'
/tmp/ccmoJQYa.s:130: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `2'
/tmp/ccmoJQYa.s:133: Error: unknown .loc sub-directive `discriminator'
/tmp/ccmoJQYa.s:133: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `1'
make[1]: *** [sdeps90.o] Error 1
```

I'm not sure that this is the right place for this question since it's mainly about compilation issues, but I don't think StackOverflow or some general programming board would be able to help out. I'm hoping that someone here has experience with the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ME57 should come with a `configure` script, so the usual `./configure; make; make install` should just work. I tried it just now using GCC 4.9.0-7 on Debian testing.

Comment: That is exactly what I did and got that error. What version of binutils did you use? I think the one on this machine might be old. The machine is running Redhat Linux.

Comment: Using an older binutils was indeed the issue. I compiled the latest version, and HSL_ME57 compiles fine. It seems to create a libfakemetis.a library as well, however (even though I supplied a working METIS lib which the configure script accepted.) Should I just ignore this? Thanks!

Comment: Where should I compile to / store the compiled library?